# How do I navigate to specific screens based on selected dropdown item in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Below is the canvas-app formula I have tried but I do not know why there is an error showing on the "DisplayBuildingDropDown":

```
Navigate(If(
        "EC - Empire Complex" in DisplayBuildingDropDown.Selected.Value, BuildingStorey,"BTB - Brani Terminal Building" in DisplayBuildingDropDown.Selected.Value, 'Testing Screen'), 
    ScreenTransition.Cover)
```

Below is the image shown for what I have mentioned above:
[image: Please view this image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the information you have provided. Is the `DisplayBuildingDropDown` bound to a list of strings?

I was able to do a simple version of what you have described without any issues. What exactly is the error you are seeing? You should be able to see it if you hover over the red squiggly lines in the formula that contains the error.

Thanks!